# Startup.cs fails when used from another assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a site-creation business and I create a lot of sites that need to be similar in many technological aspects.

I tend to reuse `Startup.cs` across these sites.

But it fails.

I have provided a sample at [GitHub](https://github.com/hosseinitabar/ReusableStartup).

```
// webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); // this works, because the Startup.cs exists in the same DLL
webBuilder.UseStartup<Base.Startup>(); // this fails, because we're using Startup.cs from another DLL.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**update**
By *this fails* I mean I receive 404 for all of my pages. And both `Startup.cs` files are exactly the same.

Comment: Can you explain `this fails` ?

Comment: @Chetan please see the update.

Comment: Define a local startup that derives from the base startup (ie: `class Startup: Base.Startup`) Make the base abstract and the members virtual/overridable

Comment: You should also take some time and get familiar with the documentation here [App startup in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup)

Answer (score 0):

After test, I found we can use `Startup.cs` file from another project. But the type of the assembly can't be library project.

#### After testing, the conclusions drawn:

*You can reference the Startup.cs file of other projects, but the referenced project should be a web project. From the Startup.cs file in your sample code, when routing and pages, they should follow the rules of the Base project to run, so you The 404 encountered is the expected behavior. This can be proved from the test results of the Base1 project.*

## Steps

I create a new one project with name `Base1`. Blow is my test result.

**1. Create a new project.**

[image]

**2. Modify the code in `Program.cs` file, both Project A and B.**

[image]

**3. Run it.**

[image]